Handling cases of "potential" ChatGPT-generated reviews in non-anonymous program committees (as a PC member)
I am currently serving on the program committee (PC) of a top-tier venue in computer science. Every paper is reviewed by 3-4 PC members; then, the authors can then see the reviews and respond with a "rebuttal." All the PC members who have reviewed a certain paper know the identities of the other PC members who reviewed the same paper. The reviewing process is double blind (authors do not know the identities of the reviewers, and reviewers do not know the identities of the authors).
The issue. I have just submitted my review for one of the papers in my stack. Upon reading the other reviews, I found one review is written in a "ChatGPT-like" style. Suffice it to say that it is not "obvious", but it's very likely that this is the case.
As a PC member -- but also as an author of a paper that was reviewed by ChatGPT -- I would like to "do something." However, I do not see anything that I can do that would lead to a happy ending. This is because I am unable to ethically prove1 that the review has been generated with ChatGPT.
As such, I am stuck. I have several options, but all of these do not lead to a happy ending:

I can contact the PC chairs. However, I cannot provide any proof, aside from mentioning the elements that make me believe that the review was generated with ChatGPT. Of course, lack of proof would also lead them to do nothing (e.g., they cannot "point the finger" to the reviewer without some solid basis).

I can ask the PC member who wrote the "suspicious" review. This is unlikely to end well, since they will most likely be defensive (if they truly used ChatGPT) or feel offended (if they did not).

I can acknowledge that I cannot prove anything, and try to induce the PC member who wrote such a review to amend the review by, e.g., pointing out specific elements in their review (which I think are vague and not informative). This may take a long time though, and may very well end with no change whatsoever.

I can just do nothing. And this would also leave a sour taste in my mouth: if the review was truly written by ChatGPT, then the authors would receive an "unfair" review, which would be quite disappointing.


If I knew the identity of the authors, I could ask for their permission to carry out the analysis myself. However, I cannot do so since the reviewing process is double blind.
Do you have any recommendation or alternative solution?

1: As I mentioned, I have been on the receiving end of a paper that (i) was rejected and (ii) for which one of the reviewers wrote their review with ChatGPT. After reading the reviews, I became suspicious and, since I was the author of the paper, I went to www.chatpdf.com, submitted the paper to it, and tried a few prompts until I found the one that produced (almost) the same review I received. However, I cannot do this "ethically" for this case: if I were to upload the paper on www.chatpdf.com, I would breach the confidentiality agreement since I would give a paper (currently under peer-review) to a third-party that is unrelated to the venue; potentially, I may compromise the novelty of the finding discussed in the paper, damaging the authors. Therefore, I am unable to prove that the review was generated with ChatGPT or similar LLM. [Somewhat related: Can I improve a paper peer-review using ChatGPT?]

It seems like you don't lose anything by at least talking with the Chair. They may do nothing, they may decide to contact the person who used Chat, or they may have some response you did not anticipate. What do you lose by contacting them?

@JoshuaZ talking with the chairs without clear evidence would (likely) annoy them, since they too cannot do much. The process of chairing a (top-tier) conference is extremely stressing nowadays, and I they have all the reasons to be annoyed if someone highlighted a "potential" problem for which they also could do little about.

I suspect you are overestimating both their likelihood of being annoyed and the level of annoyance.

This is a fairly long question for what could be written much shorter.

@AzorAhai-him- I have removed the first paragraph and put the explanation about "why I am unable to prove anything" at the bottom (since some may be aware of the reason).

The key is if the content of the review is poor or not. If there is a rebuttal phase, this can be elicited. If not, then it might make sense for the area chair to send the paper and the review for a meta-evaluation to get an idea if the reviewer actually talks about the paper in a coherent and grounded way (independently of whether they agree with the review).

But is the content of the review correct? If the reviewer looked at the paper and told chatgpt to write a review focusing on x, y, z, I don't see a problem. If the paper was so bad that even chatgpt could spot the problems, I don't see a problem.

Unless there's something really obvious like "as an AI language model", the problem is that what people consider  "ChatGPT-like style" is in reality mostly just "Nigerian english" because the models were fine-tuned with staff from nigeria https://businessday.ng/technology/article/online-uproar-over-nigerian-english-flagged-as-chatgpt-ish/
As a result, nigerian academics are sometimes getting wrongly accused of using AI based on style and terms more often used by nigerian english speakers.

For your third point, is it common for PC members to provide feedback on each other's reviews?

@DanielHatton That would be the original authors, who OP cannot contact directly due to blinded review (see the sentence in OP starting with "If I knew the identity of the authors"). Best to work with the chairs.

@Murphy I have reviewed your provided link and it does not support your claim that staff from Nigeria fine tuned the models.

@P.Shark: Maybe helpful: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/199417/132071

@cong Chen  its that nigerian staff were hired for rlhf. They weren't doing the fine tuning themselves. https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2024/apr/16/techscape-ai-gadgest-humane-ai-pin-chatgpt

Many thanks @Murphy


I can contact the PC chairs. However, I cannot provide any proof, aside from mentioning the elements that make me believe that the review was generated with ChatGPT. Of course, lack of proof would also lead them to do nothing (e.g., they cannot "point the finger" to the reviewer without some solid basis).

I think this is the best approach. You can provide the elements that give you that belief, you can explain your inability to be certain, and then you can let them decide. I would not push it much further, though; once you've brought your suspicions to light your job is done.
As far as evidence, the chairs may have other evidence to bring to the table like other reviews by the same person that you are not party to.
As far as proof, this isn't a court of law, proof is not necessary; they do not need to pillory the accused in the town square, they could instead merely choose to discount their opinion in this one specific case. If sufficiently miffed, they could choose to not invite this reviewer to participate in the future. They can potentially do either of these things without making any accusation known, and they certainly don't need to prove involvement of any specific LLM, they must merely be dissatisfied with the quality of review.

At the very least,  you should report this to the chair because the authors most likely did not agree to have their abstract harvested by an LLM, and probably don't want it to be.

+1 for "Abstract harvesting" point.

By using certain services (e.g., chatpdf.com) it is possible to upload the whole manuscript and ask to write a review for it. This is what I described at the bottom of my question :)
To provide more context: the review does mention elements that are not discernible by the abstract.

@P.Shark Yes, but you didn't list it as a reason for a course of action :)

Is only the style reminiscent of ChatGPT or is the content of the review also poor? These are different questions. For instance, a reviewer not very proficient in English could have used an LLM to improve their writing, and that may give the style of ChatGPT but human content, or the reviewer could have discussed their technical points with a machine and taken on board some in their own judgement good points the machine made, or conversely humans are entirely capable of writing very poor/misguided reviews all on their own.
Depending on the confidentiality policy of your conference, it might be still ethical to try to reproduce the review on ChatGPT using their "temporary chat" feature (which wipes the discussion from the chat history, limits storage on OpenAI servers to one month, and excludes the content from training on user data). You could also try to see if a similar review can be reproduced by one of the more powerful open-weights models by installing a copy of, say, Llama-3-70b on a sufficiently powerful server that is fully under your control and feeding that model the text. It's easy to do, if you have the required server. But I think either method will still likely give you inconclusive data. It is easy with such things to see patterns where none are there (Google Toiletgate to get a taste for how low this can go).
I would simply strongly back up the authors if they contest any factually wrong claims made in the review, and/or use reviewer discussion unprompted to contest points that I think are weak/wrong, and try to convince the other reviewers/program chairs to discount the review if it is sufficiently poor on purely technical terms. Given such feedback, if the author of the review used ChatGPT, I would hope that they learn from the experience and produce better reviews next time they are asked.

I disagree on the "temporary chat" feature.  You're still sharing confidential information with a third party, without being in control if the data are truly wiped and excluded from training.

Yes, that's why I said "maybe ethical". There would definitively be an information security risk there. However, the number of trusted parties in a typical review process for a compsci conference is big: everyone on the PC can see all papers submitted unless they have a declared conflict, stuff is sent via unencrypted email, people do reviews on both their home and institutional machines, some of them use cloud backup, authentication to the review site is user+password, submissions are stored forever... the list goes on. Rationally I don't think the temporary chat would be that much worse.

@gerrit the same applies if someone emails a copy to themselves or saves something they're reviewing to their google drive.

@Murphy google drive, yes.  E-Mail, depends.

@Murphy FWIW, I have on at least one occasion received explicit instructions during peer review to not transmit the materials by email, to cloud storage, etc. I think these things will become more commonplace as more 3rd parties amend their terms to make it clear or plausible that they are using content to train AI models that people would have previously assumed was private or used in a far less intrusive manner. (Adobe's latest terms of service changes would be an example, Microsoft's "Recall").

@Polytropos even if the email communication is encrypted end to end, it may still break a badly written confidentiality agreement that is interpreted by its letter and not by its intent. Submitting encrypted data to a 3rd party is still submitting data to a 3rd party. That's why I agree with you that using the temporary chat is probably good enough, but if not, using a model on your own server has to be good enough. Overall I agree with you that the quality of the review is what matters, not how the peer came up with it.

Since the program committee has some control over who the reviewers are, the alternate solution is to have a policy about AI generated reviews and to get reviewers to agree to abide by those policies. This should, at least, reduce the problem if it exists.
The policy should be clear and give reasons for the rules.
One possible feature of such a policy could be that the reviewer attest on submitting the review that no part of it was AI generated (or something similar).
In the short term, however, the committee should be made aware of any suspected AI generated reviews so that they can evaluate the problem.
Authors need input on their submissions and the input needs to be done by a mind with an ethical sense behind it. If it could be automated then there would be no need for reviewers. Reviewers need clear rules about many things including AI generation. Without that combination, the quality of presented and published work can and probably will decline.
And, this isn't limited to CS.

I would ignore whether the review was written with the assistance of a LLM. It isn't really important and it is hard to prove (And is there a point to proving this? Is there an explicit policy against this?) What you really have a problem with is that the review is of low quality. The same problem can easily occur without LLM assitance. Is there a procedure for when you notice a review of low quality? If so follow that. In case you can still edit your review perhaps you can discuss the points mentioned in the other review and rebut them? It also seems like you will be in the position to point out that this quality is low quality and should be ignored later on in the process, or are you not? If not you should write someone who is.

You should do absolutely nothing.
The premise makes an implication that is not shown to be true. More specifically that there's something wrong with using tools to write reviews.
Is that explicitly forbidden (although it shouldn't be in my opinion)? If yes, address it to whoever issued the policy. If it's not explicitly forbidden, then it's allowed.
The reviewer is nevertheless responsible for the reviews they sign. If they used ChatGPT and then agreed with what it says there, then it's all good. If what it says doesn't make sense, then they're responsible for what they signed nevertheless.
If they're plagiarizing, or if it's a low quality review, address that, but not that they used a glorified spell checker to improve their writing efficiency.
In the comments to this question it has been raised the issue of possibly breaking a confidentiality agreement, as some GPT tools may not be associated with the program and may involve submitting the data to a 3rd party. This doesn't necessarily seem to be the raised issue, but I find this to be a legitimate concern. In this case, the issue should be addressed directly and no proof is necessary.
It should be as simple as "Hey, I noticed a certain style of writing that made me think that you may have used a tool that may require submitting the article to a 3rd party, which may be in breach of our confidentiality agreement. Please double check that this isn't the case, and if it is, please let us know so that we can take the further appropriate steps."

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"A glorified spelling checker" - false equivalence - a spelling checker is supposed to correct what the author wrote following their path not springing off into unknown directions to harvest as much of the author's intellect as possible - and we know how twisted these simple spell checkers are with the ambiguity of straight forward English words let alone longer passages.
